# Filtering values in a row according to the value of another column

Tags: python, list, dataframe, nlp, lemmatization

I would like to create a list of specific negative words for three different labels in my training data. The word should only appears for a specific label, not the three. I have a dataframe with 3 columns: id, sentences, labels

I have also 2 different lexicon files for positive (all in lemmatized form)

I would like to create list of word for each labels

so far I succeeded in creating columns which display negative words for each sentence. but I clueless how to do after, to select and extract word which are unique for each label. That means words which appears only in sentence labelled as one of the three classes.

To summarize: I would like to create a list of words of my lexicon of words negative which appears on sentence labelled as A, B or C. Those words should be unique for each class as show on the expected output list

Datafile below

[image]

Part of script my script  (I just put the example with negative words)

```
lexiconneg = lexiconneg_feel['Word'].values # a list of negative word
print(lexiconneg)

def extract_word_neg(text, word_list):
    text_list = tokenize_lemmatize_spacy(text) # call tokenize and lemmatisation function using spacy
    
    intersection = [w for w in text_list if w in word_list]
    
    return intersection
    

datafile['list_mots_négatifs'] = datafile['phrases'].apply(extract_word_neg, args= (lexiconneg, ))

datafile.to_excel('négatif_mots.xlsx')
```

Datafile after applying script below

[image]

So for my example, I will have the following list as the expected result:

```
A=  problème, polluer, corrosif, pouvoir, sujet
B=  contrer, extrémité, bouillir
C= vider pression
```

Answer (score 0):

As I did not have the code you offered, I tried to make some random pandas dataframe here in order to work with what was proposed

```py
dataframe = pd.DataFrame(np.transpose([['problème blabla', 'contrer blabla', 'vider blabla', 'polluer blabla',
                           'corrosif blabla', 'pression blabla', 'extrémité blabla', 'invalid word', 'boullir blabla',
                           'sujet blabla', 'problème blabla', 'invalid word', 'vider blabla', 'corrosif blabla',
                           'boullir blabla', 'contrer blabla', 'invalid word', 'invalid word'],
                         ['A', 'B', 'C', 'A', 'A', 'C', 'B', 'B', 'A', 'A', 'C', 'A', 'B', 'B']]),
                         columns = ['phrases', 'labels'])

A = ['problème', 'polluer', 'corrosif', 'pouvoir', 'sujet']
B = ['contrer', 'extrémité', 'bouillir']
C = ['vider', 'pression']
```

A way to extract the "labeled" words from that that frame would be like this:

```py
A_Words = [x for x in sum([y.split() for y in dataframe.phrases[dataframe.labels=='A']], []) if x in A]
B_Words = [x for x in sum([y.split() for y in dataframe.phrases[dataframe.labels=='B']], []) if x in B]
C_Words = [x for x in sum([y.split() for y in dataframe.phrases[dataframe.labels=='C']], []) if x in C]
```

So, just explaining what is happening here to see if it can make sense:
In `[y.split() for y in dataframe.phrases[dataframe.labels=='A']]` we are creating a list that contains the splitted words from each element in the pandas dataframe that have the label `A`.

In order to flatten the list of words so we can extract only the words contained in A, B or C, we use the solution proposed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/952946/12677400)

Then we check if that word is located in the A, B or C lists, if they are, then they are added to the A_Words, etc.

I hope I could help, if it wasn't exactly this por

Comment: Thank you but I think I miswrite my problem, I would like to create a list of words of my lexicon  of words negative which appears on sentence labelled as A, B or C . Those words should be unique for each class as show on the expected output list